# How to calculate rotation angles in an accelerometer of three axes?

Tags: arduino, rotation, accelerometer, angle, measure

I´m using MXChip Kit IoT accelerometer sesnsor to calculate rotation angles when i turn it 360° BUT the sensor only gives me values from 0 to 90 dregrees so i don't know how to simulate an entire round because when it passes the 90 degrees decreases the value of the accelerometer, so the degrees also decrease to 0.

Help me please

I want to simulate the rotation in Unity but i need to give a solution to that.

Comment: Are you looking for a real function that maps values from [90 -90] to [0 360]?

Comment: maybe you should first find out how an accelerometer works. make a sketch. than it is rather obvious how to get to a 0-360° angle from sensor readings. you should get +-90 degrees btw. without signed values it won't work.
you can either use functions or  lookup tables for conversion

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon yes it is. i wanna simulate that

Comment: @Piglet The sensor works like this... When it is in horizontal position, it gives the maximum value that is gravity. When i'm turning the value decreases to zero that is when it is vertical position (0° to 90°). When i continous turning it the value incrases to maximum value again (90° to 0°). I need to find an algorithm to calculate full turn.

Comment: @JaverBenavidez an accelerometer outputs ±90° per axis.

Comment: @Piglet Yes i know but i need to simulate a full turn. That is my problem